# How to access ajax json input in restful webservice?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, rest

I have an RESTful webservice that consumes a JSON response and I am making an ajax call to the web service as show below.

When I am trying to invoke web service, I am getting `404 (Not Found)` error. Please let me know what's the issue with my code. I searched for similar posts and I couldn't find an answer.

AJAX code is:

```
$('#addUser').click(function(){
var userDetails = getUserRegistrationFormInfo();
$.ajax ({
    url: 'RestfulWS/rest/restful/addUser',
    contentType: 'applicaiton/json',
    type: "POST",
    data: userDetails,
    success: function (response) {
        // Success callback
        alert('Hey');            
    }})
});


function getUserRegistrationFormInfo(){
    return JSON.stringify({
        "userId": parseInt($('#userId').val()),
        "name": $('#userName').val(),
        "addressLine": $('#address').val(),
        "emaiId": $('#email').val()
    });
}
});
```

And Restful web service code is:

```
  @POST
      @Path("/addUser")
      @Consumes("applicaiton/json")
      public Response addUser(User user){
          //userMap.put(Integer.toString(user.getUserId()), user);
          userMap.put("123", user);
         return Response.ok().build();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a routing issue in your application. Try to access your REST URL from a web browser, developer console such as Firebug, or simply ping it. If you still get a 404, adjust the request URL to match your web service route, or fix the routing.

Please note that the correct naming for the content type in this case is `application/json`. If this typo is also in your code, maybe start by adjusting it.

Comment: I corrected the URL and the typo in content type and it worked. Thanks a lot adriann